# R - Sys.time() and as.POSIXct() issue

Tags: r, date, time, triggers

I want to run a code when sys.time() is specified.

I don't understand why if I write:

```
inputTime <- as.POSIXct("2018-02-21 14:51:00")

while(TRUE) {
  if(Sys.time() == inputTime){
    a <- 5
    b <- 6
    c <- a+b

    print(c)
  } 
}
```

I don't get any result, but if I write something like:

```
inputTime <- Sys.time()+3

while(TRUE) {
  if(Sys.time() == inputTime){
    a <- 5
    b <- 6

    c <- a+b

    print(c)
  } 
}
```

I get the result I was looking for (11 in this case).

Can you please help me?

Comment: Could it be because `as.POSIXct("2018-02-21 14:51:00")` is in the past and thus `Sys.time()` would never equal it going forward, whereas `Sys.time()+3` is, by definition, 3 seconds in the future?

Comment: Hi @ktdrv, the date I inserted was just an example. Of course I put a future date, but it seems that Sys.time() and the given date do not match...

Comment: Same thing if I write: for (i in 1:50){ (Sys.time() == inputTime) }. With inputTime <- whatever you want, nothing happens... I really don't understand why